# Drag and drop row on KendoUI Grid with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-draggable

How can I make a row in a KendoUI Grid draggable with AngularJs?

The documentation says you have to initialize the draggable component with a filter ie "tbody > tr", but I don't understand how to apply the kendo-draggable directive on just the rows.

This is how I initialize kendo-grid:

```
<div 
    kendo-grid
    k-options="activityGridOptions"
    k-rebind="activityGridOptions"
></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to define a rowTemplate and altRowTemplate on the config object and adding a template inside the html like so:

```
<!-- Grid row template -->
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="grid-row-template">
    <tr data-uid="#= uid #" draggable draggable-data="dataItem" draggable-type="'planner.activity'" ng-class="{'current-item': currentActivityId == dataItem.SyncTableUniqueId}" ng-click="setCurrentActivity(dataItem)">
        <td>{{dataItem.AvtaleNr}}.{{dataItem.VareLøpenummer}}</td>
        <td>
            {{dataItem.Date| moment:'ll'}} {{dataItem.Time| moment:'HH:mm':'HH:mm:ss'}}
        </td>
        <td>{{dataItem.FirstName}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

As you might notice, I am using a non-kendo draggable directive. The rowTemplate and altRowTemplate is assigned inside my controller:

```
$scope.activityGridOptions = {
    dataSource: $scope.gridDataSource,
    // ...
    rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#grid-row-template").html()),
    altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#grid-row-template").html())
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, you can try to use this angular directive:

https://github.com/neoziro/angular-draganddrop